# How to prevent rod/shaft from sliding

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I'm new to mechanical engineering and have a question regarding something that I design using fusion 360.

Here I have 2 wooden rollers that are mounted on 2 side plates thru holes. I'm planning to use sprockets and chain connected to these rods/shafts outside the side plates and a crank handle to power them.
My questions are

1. And how do I make sure that these rods wouldn't slide horizontally when the crank handle is rotated that would misalign the sprockets and chain.
2. Since the thickness of the plate is only 5mm, I don't know if I should use a bearing to hold these rods or the hole is enough or any other thing(I'm not familiar with names of these parts to be used).

[image: design]

Comment: get yourself a lego technics set or a meccano set or something similar ... it will help you understand basic mechanical concepts

Comment: @jsotola I might give it a try. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the thickness of the plate is only 5mm, I don't know if I should use a bearing to hold these rods or the hole is enough or any other thing(I'm not familiar with names of these parts to be used).

Yes, absolutely use a bearings or bushings. You want those bearings or bushings. Thickness of the material it is riding in is irrelevant as long as it sits square.

You do not want the outer race of the bearing to rotate relative to whatever it is mounted in, nor do you want the shaft to rotate against the inner race of the ball bearing. That defeats the purpose of the bearing. The goal is to have relative motion *only* occur between the balls and races of the bearing.

There are at least a few ways to do this:

1. Press fit (works for both inner race and outer race)
2. Slip fit with set screws (only works for the shaft and inner race)
3. Slip fit with adhesive such as green threadlocker (works for both inner race and outer race)

You can also get bearings and bushings with flanges or shoulders which can help if you are using a slip fit mounting for the outer race.

It is obviously okay for the shaft to rotate against the inner surface of a bushing since that is how a bushing works. Therefore you obviously do not want press fits or adhesives or set screws to prevent the shaft from rotating in the bushing. However, the outside of the bushing should not rotate relative to its mount just like the outer race of a bearing.

> And how do I make sure that these rods wouldn't slide horizontally when the crank handle is rotated that would misalign the sprockets and chain.

There at at least a few common ways to stop the shaft from sliding lengthwise in the inner race of the bearing, in order of increasing security and elegance, but increasing complexity, cost, and convenience of assembly:

1. shaft collars
2. grooves with retaining rings in them, but there are also retaining rings designed to dig into the shaft so do not need grooves
3. put shoulders on the shaft

I suppose in some cases you might be able to get away with using adhesive between the shaft and inner race of the bearing, but this is not a proper method to prevent lengthwise sliding.

Comment: I'm little confused due to lack of knowledge on the subject. I thought the bearings have to be part of the side plate in order to avoid friction. Since the thickness of the plate is so small, I wouldn't get the bearings of right size to be fitted properly inside the plate. My question is does the bearings and side plate need to be in contact or it can be independent and held together by placing them closely with the help of snap clips or something?

Comment: By meaning right size, I was thinking that the thickness of the plate must be bigger than the thickness of the bearing for it to be press fitted inside the bore of the plate. I got some ideas from your post on that, but i'm not sure which one would be easier and cheaper as this is only gonna be a prototype.

Comment: @Questions I do not see how plate thickness is relevant here. 5mm is plenty thick for a bearing. The goal is to have the relative motion between surfaces only occur between the balls and races of the bearing. That means that the outer race must not rotate against whatever it is mounted on and the shaft must not rotate relative to the inner race. There are many ways to do this: adhesive, set screws, flanges, press-fits, mounting plates, etc.

Comment: @Questions Why do you think the plate needs to be thicker than the bearing? Sure that is often what you see but why do you think it *must* be like that? 5mm is thick enough that a bearing of typical thickness can be held square in the hole. What else do you think matters?

Comment: What you go with depends on the tools you have. Press fit is "the best" but also will requires the most precise machining and possibly an arbor presses for assembly or disassembly . Press fits need fits accurate to 0.0001"~0.0003" for steel to produce that you would need to bore and ream on a mill. Although nothing is stopping you from just gluing the bearing in the hole. That's what green Loctite is used for.

Comment: I came to that understanding when I checked with one of the guy on hardware shops that sells bearing. I don't have any tools to do this myself and I'll have to outsource the work once the design is finished. As I mentioned earlier I'm a complete noob on mechanical engineering and the terminologies. Only after your post I get hold of some of the names of the parts.

Comment: If someone else is doing it you might as well get them to do a press-fit or a slip fit. Press fit is best but if you don't have access to an arbour press or it costs too much then you can go slip fit and just "glue" the bearing in to stop it from rotating. That's what green loctite is for and that's also what you can use to stop the shaft from rubbing against the bearing's inner race. That may not be sufficient to stop the shaft from sliding lengthwise in the inner race though. A shoulders on the shaft is the "best" for that but far more expensive and inconvenient to assemble.

Comment: The reason press fit might cost too much is they may not be able to just take a cut of the material and be done with it. They may have to take a cut and try to mate the parts together to see if they fit and if it doesn't take another identical cut. Just because you move your cutting blade in by 0.001" doesn't mean it actually took 0.001" of material off.

Comment: I now got a fair idea on this and I'll spend time learning which one would suit my application. Thanks a ton for explaining many things clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use bearings on both ends of each shaft and locate the bearings in place with grooves in the shafts with circlips or similar.

Or, turn down the outer ends of the shafts to give a register for the bearings to locate against and thread the shaft for locking nuts.

Other possibilities are also possible.

Comment: I assume in the first method, the bearings are placed on the shaft and held close to the the side plate with the help of circlips?